# tkinter and refreshing values for display

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm incredibly new to tkinter, but I love the ability to have a gui with my python apps. I'm working on a monitor app for some low level home automation and I want to display some active readings that'll change.

I've googled how to do this but without much luck so far. I'm hoping someone can point this out to me on how I could make these values refresh.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w1 = Label(root, text="reading1: "+str(readings[0]), justify='left', wraplength=100)
w2 = Label(root, text="reading2: "+str(readings[1]), justify='right', wraplength=100)

w1.pack(side='left')
w2.pack(side='right')

root.title("Test Automation")
root.minsize(800, 400)

root.mainloop()
```

There's more to the code, but I don't believe it's necessary for this example. Like I said, if readings[0] changes, how can I reflect that in the gui?

Comment: use `root.after(miliseconds, function_name_without_())` to periodically run function which checks `reading[0]` and changes label text `w1['text'] = "Hello World"`

Comment: see [clock](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/tkinter/timer-using-after/clock-function.py) using `after`